# Change page margins in LyX

Tags: lyx, margins

I use LyX 2.1, and I want to change the margins of a document as follows:

- Top and bottom: 2.5
- Right: 2
- Left: 3

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ideally there should be just one question per post, so consider posting the second question as a new question. Also, do you want both image and capion framed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Document --> Settings --> Page Margins, uncheck the box at the top for *Default margins*, and modify the values to suit your needs.

The *Inner* and *Outer* margin correspond to left and right margins respectively for one-sided documents, such as the default `article`. For two-sided documents (e.g. `book`) the inner margin is that closest to the spine of the book, so the left margin on odd-numbered pages, and the right margin on even-numbered pages.

Comment: this concerns only the top and bottom but I have not found the right and left.

Comment: @user1936895 Inner and outer.

Comment: inner is right and outer is left?

Comment: No, other way around. Sorry, could have been clearer. (I edited my answer before posting the comment.)